# What is the default root password for DSLinux?

Tags: linux, passwords, root, damn-small-linux

What's the default root password in DSLinux, or in any Linux distribution?

I didn't set it.

Answer (score 2):

Should be **"uClinux"** for DS Linux.

Comment: welcome to super user! this is different from typical forum sites.  you shouldn't refer to other answers as "next answer" or "previous answer"; answer positions might change over time. (you're welcome to add a permalink or refer to *so-and-so's answer* or similar.)

Comment: Well, i'm new... :-) Thanks for the advice.

Comment: The custom is to prefix names with an @ when referencing somebody else's answer or comment, or when responding to someone like in this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Debian and Debian-based distributions like Ubuntu tend to leave the root password empty (thus disabling the root login).  They prefer you to access superuser functions by using ***sudo*** in your main user account, or by booting the system into single-user mode.

Under these systems you can always set a root password with:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Answer (score 0):

Damn Small Linux comes with two users, these are:

```
Name | Password
root | toor
dsl  | reverse
```

These are listed on the [DSL download page](https://virtualboxes.org/images/damn-small/).